# Probability notation question: differences between undergraduate and graduate texts

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

Suppose $X$ is a random variable. In most undergraduate math texts, one writes the expected value of $X$ as $\text{E}X$ or $\text{E}[X]$. Similarly, the probability that $X$ is greater than some value $x$ is usually written as $\text{P}(X > x)$ or $\Pr(X > x)$.

However, in most graduate-level treatments of probability that I have read, I notice $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ are used instead.

Is there any particular reason for this change of style of notation?

[If anyone can make this a community wiki, I'd appreciate it.]

Comment: It's just different notation. I'm not sure I agree that the statistics differ considerably between undergraduate and graduate texts, though I haven't done any statistics myself. It is more probable that the convention depends on the subarea.

Comment: As you progress in mathematics you get to use cooler and cooler notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why there would be an increased usage of $\mathbb{E}$ over $\mathbf{E}$ in graduate texts, but, basically, $\mathbb{E}$ is supposed to represent the stylized way people draw bold fonts on a chalkboard (or in your notes).  The only difference between $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ is the font.

Perhaps the reason for the increased usage is that there has been a fairly recent explosion in the number of graduate mathematics texts published, and while the undergraduate library has grown as well, it has grown more slowly.  So you are more likely to see newer styles in books for more advanced topics.